# How to check if a file or folder is a symbolic link, using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, symlink

I know how to check if a file/folder exists, but wonder how I can check if a file/folder is a symbolic link with AppleScript.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can provide your **input in the form of POSIX-style paths** (`/` as separator), here's a handler that uses `do shell script` and the shell's `-L` file-test operator:

```applescript
on isSymlink(posixPath)
    try
        do shell script "[[ -L " & quoted form of posixPath & " ]]"
        return true
    end try
    return false
end isSymlink

# Sample call.
my isSymlink("/User Guides And Information")  # -> true

# If you have an HFS-style path (':' as the separator), simply prepend
# `POSIX path of`.
my isSymlink(POSIX path of "Macintosh HD:User Guides And Information")
```

**Things to note**:

- The handler will also return `false` if the specified file/folder doesn't exist at all.
- Applying `alias` to an HFS-style path string representing a symlink results in instant resolution of the symlink to its target; in other words: the object returned represents the symlink's *target* (original), not the symlink itself; e.g.:

```applescript
    # Returns reference to *target*, 
    # "Macintosh HD:Library:Documentation:User Guides And Information.localized:"
    alias "Macintosh HD:User Guides And Information"
```

- The same happens in the `System Events` context with a `file` / `folder` specifier: the *target* is returned:

```applescript
    tell application "System Events"
      # Returns reference to *target* folder, 
      # "Macintosh HD:Library:Documentation:User Guides And Information.localized:"
      folder "Macintosh HD:User Guides And Information"
    end tell
```

- To **truly get a reference to a symlink - represented as class `alias file` in AppleScript - always use `tell application "Finder"` and object specifier `file`, even if the symlink's *target* is a *folder***:

```applescript
    tell application "Finder"
        file "Macintosh HD:User Guides And Information" # -> alias file 
    end tell
```

- Also note that **it isn't only symlinks that are represented as `alias file` instances - Finder's own alias files (created by control-clicking an item and selecting `Make Alias`) are represented the same way - use the `file type` property to distinguish them**: true symlinks return `slnk` (sic), whereas Finder aliases return `alis` (sic).

---

In light of the above: If you still want a **handler for the limited use case of testing whether a `Finder` `file [alias]` object is a symlink**:

```applescript
on isSymlinkFile(fileObj)
    try
        return "slnk" is file type of fileObj
    end try
    return false
end isSymlinkFile


# Sample call.
tell application "Finder"
    set f to file "Macintosh HD:User Guides And Information"
    my isSymlinkFile(f) # -> true
end tell
```